# Hardware wallets and Plausible Deniability

Tags: hardware-wallets

One question referring to these articles:

https://blog.trezor.io/hide-your-trezor-wallets-with-multiple-passphrases-f2e0834026eb

and

http://support.ledgerwallet.com/knowledge_base/topics/advanced-passphrase-options

My question is: is it really already plausible with just 2048 words? Could an adversary not just brute-force all 2048 combinations and check if there are transactions on the blockchain behind these addresses? I think finding an address in this space could already make it unplausible - but I am not yet sure - hence I ask ;-)
Still like the idea and think it is a very good decoy - but I am not yet sure if it counts as "plausible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passphrase is not limited to the 2048 words list, it could be anything, any string.

Comment: Thanks! This explains it - naming it the "25th" word lead to a wrong assumption on my side.